# Computer blanking out after 3 hours of video conversion

Tags: cpu-usage, video-conversion

I've experienced this for the 2nd time around. But after I have done a video conversion from .mov to .avi. Using total video converter, the computer monitor doesn't display anything. I turn it off then turn it on again, but the monitor said: 'no signal'.
Do you think that it was the heavy cpu usage of converting videos made this?
Do you think that the applications iisted here can actually lower the cpu usage and the heat dissipated by the cpu while I convert videos?
[Are there solutions that can limit the CPU usage of a process?](https://superuser.com/questions/214566/how-to-limit-cpu-usage-of-a-process)

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your GPU is overheating. Use tools such as *[GPU-Z](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/)*, *[Speedfan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php)*, *[Real Temp](http://www.techpowerup.com/realtemp/)*, or *[MSI Afterburner](http://event.msi.com/vga/afterburner/download.htm)* to monitor the temperature of the GPU and CPU as you are doing a conversion.

To prevent the GPU from overheating, make sure your computer is well ventilated, is located in a cool place, and has a sufficient number of fans.