# How to reduce the CPU speed to 1% of actual CPU speed for a specific Windows process?

Tags: windows-7, windows, cpu

I have a Windows software with a GUI that does cool things but too quickly (I cannot figure see all the editing it does in realtime because it goes too fast).

How to reduce the CPU speed to 1% of actual CPU speed for a specific Windows process `myprogram.exe` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, [this might be useful.](https://superuser.com/questions/214566/are-there-solutions-that-can-limit-the-cpu-usage-of-a-process)

In all honesty, isn't it more effective to run a Screen Recorder and slow it down?